On the continuity of a function, again
Sorry to bother you with another question on continuity, but I need experts to explain me things. I cannot interact with books only.
So the question is this: we know a definition of continuity thought limits, that says that $f$ is continuous at a point $x_0$ in the domain iff we have
$$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$$
So far so good. Now, this is what I thought and a related example will be given. I would like you to tell me if/why my reasoning is wrong or incomplete.
From the definition above I can write
$$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) - f(x_0) = 0$$ and again without loss of generality (I think)
$$\lim_{x\to x_0} |f(x) - f(x_0)| = 0$$
Which is what I believe it is usually written as $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$ as $x \to x_0$ or as $|x - x_0| < \delta$.
Now my question is: why can't we just use the fist part in a slightly modified way, that is
$$|f(x) - f(x_0)| \to d(x) \quad \text{as} \quad x \to x_0$$
Where $d$ is a distance function, which we are sure $d(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. For example, distances in $\mathbb{R}$ could be: $x, x^2, kx^2$...
And here is the example: suppose we have $f: (0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x) = x^2$. Show that $f$ is continuous at $x = 1$ and at $x = 0$ (here I will go deeper).

For $x = 1$ we thence would just have

$$|f(x) - f(1)| = |x^2 - 1| \to 0 \quad{as} \quad x \to 1$$
Why wouldn't this be enough?

For $x = 0$ it may seem to have a contradiction to what I said above that is that $x_0$ must belong to the domain. But what if we extended the definition to internal points? In this case $0$ is an internal point, and $x^2$ is well defined at $0$, thence the above reasoning would repeat.

Please forgive me if I wrote a load of nonsense. I am just here to learn, and those questions I need to ask because I have to know where my thinking is wrong.
Thank you for your time.

What is an internal point?

Also, are you purporting to define continuity at points outside the domain by suddenly including them in the domain and then saying that result is continuous?

"$|f(x) - f(x_0)| \to d(x) \quad \text{as} \quad x \to x_0$ doesn't really make sense.  Since you are taking $x \to x_0$, you cannot use $x$ in the result of the limit.  In the expression $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = L$ $x$ is a dummy variable only, and any expression for $L$ cannot have $x$. Any given $x$ is too far away from $x_0$ - we are interested only in what happens as $x$ becomes arbitrarily close to $x_0$. Also, your example  doesn't seem to involve any distance function $d(x)$, so I'm not sure what you are getting at.

But you might be interested in the notion of metric space where distance functions $d(x,y)$ measuring the distance from $x$ to $y$ are important.  In a metric space the definition of continuity at $x_0$ can be written: For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ so that for all $x$, $d(x_0, x) < \delta$ implies $d(f(x_0), f(x)) < \epsilon$.

You are beginning to reinvent the wheel.  $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ doesn't $\to$ (the distance between $f(x)$ and $f(x_0)$). $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ is EXACTLY (the distance between $f(x)$ and $f(x_0)$).  And that is basically the concept continuity. $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if the distance between $f(x)$ and $f(x_0)$ tends to $0$ as the distance between $x$ and $x_0$ tends to $0$.  The issue is $\to$ is imprecise and not well defined.  Which is where the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition comes in.  To be cont.....

I suppose one way we could teach continuity is to say: We can force the distance between $f(x)$ and $f(x_0)$ to be within any small distance $d$ so the (distance between $f(x)$ and $f(x_0))\le d$ by forcing the (distance between $x$ and $x_0)\le D$ for some distance $D$.  But that is exactly what $\delta\epsilon$ is wit $d=\epsilon;D=\delta;$(distance between $f(x)$ and $f(x_0))=|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ and (distance between $x$ and $x_0)= |x-x_0|$.

@Randall The definition of internal point is well established, and as I said in the question: FIRST I defined continuity at points in the domain, but then I thought to give some sense, even if I recognise there is not much of it, to internal points. But this was a bad statement, so I withdraw this nonsense :)

@fleablood Thank you for the comment, I understood I expressed myself badly. What I wanted to say is: could we define continuity using distance in the sense that if I can upper bound the quantity $|f(x) - f(x_0)|$ with a function of a distance, then I'm done? What I wrote in the question doesn't make much sense, but this is what I meant:
$$|f(x) - f(x_0)| \leq d(x, x_0)$$
So when $x\to x_0$ we know $d(x_0, x_0) \to 0$

@JairTaylor Thank you! Since I cannot tag two persons at once, I ask you to read the comment I wrote above, just to tell me if I'm wrong again

This sentence you wrote does not make sense :
$$|f(x) - f(x_0)| \to d(x) \quad \text{as} \quad x \to x_0$$
It does not stand on its own. What $|f(x) - f(x_0)|$ tend to as $x \to x_0$ needs to be a constant. Plus, it seems all you want is to set :
$$\lim_{x \to x_0}|f(x) - f(x_0)| = d(x_0)$$
or to set $d(x)$ to be a function agreeing with $|f(x) - f(x_0)|$ in a neighborhood of $x$ around $x_0$. In either way, it is not very clear what the point is.

Thank you for the comment, I understood I expressed myself badly. What I wanted to say is: could we define continuity using distance in the sense that if I can upper bound the quantity $|f(x) - f(x_0)|$ with a function of a distance, then I'm done? What I wrote in the question doesn't make much sense, but this is what I meant:
$$|f(x) - f(x_0)| \leq d(x, x_0)$$
So when $x\to x_0$ we know $d(x_0, x_0) \to 0$

This is a strictly stronger definition of continuity, called Lipschitz continuity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity .
